# Hide "menu" button in android app player on Blackberry 10

Tags: android, button, menu, hide, blackberry-10

How can I hide "menu" button in Android app player on Blackberry 10 (there is no menu in my android app, but when I run it on BB10 - this button appears (and obviously does nothing when clicked))?

[image]

Comment: You don't have any optionsmenu?

Comment: @Ahmad Yes, I don't have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot hide or change things to that bar, I am afraid. It is all up to the user if it should be hidden or not.

I read on some threads on the Support Forums of BlackBerry that they try to make it possible for developers to hide this bar in the new Jelly Bean update. So for now there is nothing you can do to hide/change this bar.

Comment: I want to hide only "menu" button, not the whole bar

Comment: The answer remains the same. As far as I know, you have no control over that bar, not even the buttons that are on it.

Answer (score -1):

I use this code and it worked:

```
thepage.actionBarVisibility = ChromeVisibility.Hidden
```